# Get Custom Fields on Category Page

Tags: php, opencart

Recently I bought an extension to create custom fields for my products.
This extensions works great in my products page, displays all the info i put on admin. But I need to display these custom fields in category page too, so I can list some info.

I tried copy the code and put on category(**Controller** and **View**), but it returns empty - Nothing is displayed: no errors, no warnings.. and no info.

The extension comes with a vqmod file, mostly with operations in the **catalog** folder:

**Changes in Catalog:**
Product/Controller:

```
$this->data['text_download'] = $this->language->get('text_download');

        if ($this->config->get('cpf_fields')) {
           $fields = $this->config->get('cpf_fields');
        } else {
           $fields = array();
        }

        $field_data = array();

        if (!empty($product_info['cpf'])) {
           $cpf = unserialize($product_info['cpf']);
        } else {
           $cpf = array();
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/option');

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
           $option = $this->model_catalog_option->getOption($field['option_id']);

           if ($option) {
              if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio') {
                 $values = array();

                 $option_values = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionValues($field['option_id']);

                 foreach ($option_values as $option_value) {
                    $selected = (!empty($cpf[$field['option_id']])) ? $cpf[$field['option_id']] : 0;

                    $values[] = array(
                       'option_value_id'      => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                       'name'               => $option_value['name'],
                       'selected'            => $selected
                    );
                 }

                 $field_data[] = array(
                    'name'          => $option['name'],
                    'type'          => $option['type'],
                    'status'      => $field['status'],
                    'sort_order'   => $field['sort_order'],
                    'values'      => $values
                 );
              } elseif ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') {
                 $values = array();

                 $option_values = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionValues($field['option_id']);

                 foreach ($option_values as $option_value) {
                    $selected = (!empty($cpf[$field['option_id']]) && is_array($cpf[$field['option_id']]) && in_array($option_value['option_value_id'], $cpf[$field['option_id']])) ? $option_value['option_value_id'] : 0;

                    $values[] = array(
                       'option_value_id'      => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                       'name'               => $option_value['name'],
                       'selected'            => $selected
                    );
                 }

                 $field_data[] = array(
                    'name'          => $option['name'],
                    'type'          => $option['type'],
                    'status'      => $field['status'],
                    'sort_order'   => $field['sort_order'],
                    'values'      => $values
                 );
              } else {
                 $value = (!empty($cpf[$field['option_id']])) ? $cpf[$field['option_id']] : '';;

                 $field_data[] = array(
                    'name'          => $option['name'],
                    'type'          => $option['type'],
                    'status'      => $field['status'],
                    'sort_order'   => $field['sort_order'],
                    'value'         => $value
                 );
              }
           }
        }

        $sort_order = array(); 

        foreach ($field_data as $key => $value) {
           $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
        }

        array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $field_data);

        $this->data['fields'] = array();

        foreach ($field_data as $field) {
           $this->data['fields'][] = $field;
        }
```

Product View:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field) { ?>
          <?php if ($field['status'] && (!empty($field['value']) || !empty($field['values']))) { ?>
             <?php $selected = false; ?>
             <?php if ($field['type'] == 'select' || $field['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
              <?php foreach ($field['values'] as $value) { ?>
                <?php if ($value['selected'] && !$selected) { ?>
                  <?php $selected = true; ?>
                 <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($value['selected'] == $value['option_value_id']) { ?>
                 <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?><?php if ($selected) { ?><br /><?php } ?>
             <?php } elseif ($field['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
              <?php $checkbox_value = ''; ?>
              <?php foreach ($field['values'] as $value) { ?>
                <?php if ($value['selected'] && !$selected) { ?>
                  <?php $selected = true; ?>
                 <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($value['selected'] == $value['option_value_id']) { ?>
                 <?php $checkbox_value .= $value['name'] . ', '; ?>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php echo substr($checkbox_value, 0, -2); ?><?php if ($selected) { ?><br /><?php } ?>
             <?php } elseif ($field['type'] == 'file') { ?>
              <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
              <a href="index.php?route=product/product/download&file=<?php echo $field['value']; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a><br />
             <?php } else { ?>
              <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
              <?php echo $field['value']; ?><br />
             <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Product Model is only:

```
'cpf'     => $query->row['cpf']
```

However in **ADMIN** product model the following code is injected:

```
    if (isset($data['cpf'])) {          
                foreach ($data['cpf'] as $language_id => $cpf) {
                    $cpf = serialize($cpf);

                    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET cpf = '" . $this->db->escape($cpf) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "'");
                }
            } else {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET cpf = '' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            }
```

My question is how can I get these same info and display it in another view, like category or search, or manufacturer?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the extension is storing those custom field values into a separate DB table that is not being populated when loading products for categories, manufacturers, search, latest, related, bestseller, etc. listing.

Your bet is to explore also the **model** class(es) of that extension and make sure the related table(s) are joined and required columns are loaded when retrieving the products list...

After the right data is populated Your controller and view should work as You have prepared them for...

Comment: Hi @shadyyx thank you for the reply. I guess I'm out of luck cause the only code injected at catalog model is the simple line I provided. However I edited the question adding the Admin/Model. These are the only Model* code I found in vqmod file. I saw that the extension uses OPTIONS to add these custom fields and I guess it's not using another table :)